# Android: Disable default vibration of OnLongClick

Tags: android

Is there a way to disable the vibration for the OnLongClick event?

I want no vibration or if enabled a custom vibration.

EDIT:
Thank you that did it!

Comment: for your searches use the term "haptic feedback" instead of "vibration"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure. If you look in the base [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class, there are several options for haptic feedback, such as:

A boolean XML attribute: `android:hapticFeedbackEnabled`
and its related Java method: `setHapticFeedbackEnabled(boolean)`

There are other related methods such as `performHapticFeedback()` that you can call, but if you've disabled haptic feedback in the View, you'll have to pass a flag to override the View's setting, and perform it anyway. There are some constants you can pass, located in [`HapticFeedbackConstants`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html), to get different vibration patterns from the system. To do a custom one, you'd have to override your onLongClick method and get an instance of the VIBRATOR service and have it perform a custom vibration pattern from there.